# Make a list of consecutive numbers in R

Tags: r, list

I want to make a list of consecutive numbers like this:

```
 list(1,2,3,4)
```

Gives list of four.

Now I don't want to write all numbers, so try:

```
 list(1:4)
```

Gives List of length four.

If I want to make a list of four without writing all the numbers what could be the syntax?

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  `as.list(1:4)`

```
as.list(1:4)
```

> [[1]] [1] 1
>
> [[2]] [1] 2
>
> [[3]] [1] 3
>
> [[4]] [1] 4

#### EDIT

or `as.list(seq(4))`

#### EDIT #2

Here's a speed comparison using `microbenchmark`:

```
microbenchmark(as.list(1:4), as.list(seq(4)), Map(c,1:4), sapply(1:4, list), times=1e6)
Unit: microseconds
              expr   min    lq      mean median     uq      max neval
      as.list(1:4) 1.472 2.088  2.639712  2.314  2.584 32594.44 1e+06
   as.list(seq(4)) 3.934 5.359  6.514579  5.818  6.337 31498.31 1e+06
       Map(c, 1:4) 3.435 5.052  6.243628  5.516  6.041 32628.84 1e+06
 sapply(1:4, list) 6.892 9.358 11.282727 10.009 10.757 34269.70 1e+06
```

Comment: The benchmark results would be much easier to read/compare if you put them all in a single `microbenchmark()` call.

Comment: @GregorThomas I think it's plenty easy, but thanks for the suggestion - will update.

Answer (score 2):

We could use

```
sapply(1:4, list)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] 1
>
> [[2]]
> [1] 2
>
> [[3]]
> [1] 3
>
> [[4]]
> [1] 4
> ```

```
all.equal(sapply(1:4, list), list(1,2,3,4))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code with `Map`

```
Map(c,1:4)
```

such that

```
> Map(c,1:4)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4
```